# Reading Build Order Messages from the output window pane (VSIX)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, vsix

I am building a vsix extension which reads build order messages. I am able to write on the output pane but I do not know how to read from the output window pane. So what I am doing right now is

```
IVsOutputWindow outputWindow =Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow)) as IVsOutputWindow;
                Guid guidGeneral = Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.OutputWindowPaneGuid.DebugPane_guid;
                IVsOutputWindowPane pane;
                int hr = outputWindow.CreatePane(guidGeneral, "Debug", 1, 0);
                hr = outputWindow.GetPane(guidGeneral, out pane);
                pane.Activate();
                pane.OutputString("Test");
```

Why I need to read the exception message ?
I need the exception message that is occurred in the program. It's not about the try catch block. I am looking for a generic visual studio service. Thanks in advance